How to use page breaks when printing multiple rows of a table in HTML?
I have a table in HTML where users can add rows as much as they want. However, when the table is long and I print the form, the form is cut off, and the other rows are not visible. What I want to happen is that every 10 rows, the next row (11th and then 21st and so on) should move to the next page when I print, and the footer of the page should move too.
What I think I could do is to utilize page breaks, but I can't seem to visualize how I would use it in my HTML code for the table since most of the page break samples that I see for tables have a fixed number of rows therefore they can put the page break in different classes. I already tried to add a page break for my td but it doesnt work and the whole page is still cut. Here is the sample code of my table:
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Building Number</th>
        <th>Building Type</th>
        <th>Fund Source/s</th>
        <th>Specific Fund Source/s</th>
        <th>Building Condition</th>
        <th>Number of Storeys</th>
        <th>Number of Rooms</th>
        <th>Year </th>
        <th>Classification of Building</th>
        <th>Is building PWD Accessible?</th>
        <th>Have undergone major repair for the last 5 years</th>
        <th>With Certificate of Acceptance</th>
        <th>Is the school building included in the Book of Accounts</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
        <td>
          <select name="isPWDAccessible">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="majorRepair">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="certificateOfAcceptance">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="Accounts">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>



Just use CSS page-break-after Property that place page breaks only in print view. Implement a css class so whenever you need you can reuse that class.


 @media print {
     .page-break {
         page-break-after: always;
     }
 }
<button onclick="window.print();">print</button>
<table>
    <thead>
        <!-- Table Header -->
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Content 1 -->
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Content 2 -->
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Page Break -->
        <tr class="page-break" />
        <!-- Form Row -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



